# Inward heat flow

Tags: thermodynamics

Firstly, is inward heat flow the same as inward heat flux? and which types of substances (e.g  solid , liquid, gas) can inward heat flow occur in when the temperature remains constant?

Answer (score 0):

By heat flux is intended flow of heat energy per unit of time and per unit of surface area. See e.g. [Newton's cooling law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Heat_transfer_version_of_the_law):

$$\Phi=\frac{1}{A}\frac{dQ}{dt}=h\Delta T(t)$$

Where $\Phi$ is the heat flux.

There isn't much point to referring to heat flow as 'inward' (or 'outward'): heat always flows from hot to cold. As a consequence the answer to the question:

> can inward heat flow occur in when the temperature remains constant?

... is that only if heat is constantly removed from the heat flow receiving object. Similarly, a cooling object will obviously reduce in temperature, unless the removed heat is constantly replaced.

And heat can only flow from a hotter to a cooler object.

Comment: Bulk temperature can remain constant with $\Phi \ne 0$ during phase changes.